# why Argument of type "Dataset" cannot be assigned to parameter "train_dataset" of type "Dataset[Unknown]?

Tags: nlp, dataset, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

> I am trying to finetune a large language model. and when i give train and test dataset to the model it shows the above error and there is red line under train_dataset and test_dataset.**Following is the lines where i have problem**

```
trainer = Trainer(
model=base_model,
args=training_args,
train_dataset=tokenized_train_data,
eval_dataset=tokenized_test_data
  )
```

> **This is how i am mapping and preprocess the data**
> *My dataset is in dataframe so*

```
train_dataset, test_dataset = train_test_split(concatinate_dataset_refined, test_size=0.2, random_state=132)
```

> Converting into Datasets.

```
train_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(train_dataset)
test_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(test_dataset)
```

> Tokenising

```
def tokenize_function(example):
merged = example["title"] + " " + example["story"]
batch = tokenizer(merged, padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=128)
batch["labels"] = batch["input_ids"].copy()
return batch  

# Apply it to our dataset, and remove the text columns
```

tokenized_train_data = train_dataset.map(tokenize_function, remove_columns=["title", "story"])

tokenized_test_data = test_dataset.map(tokenize_function, remove_columns=["title", "story"])

**Even i run the code it model runs okay but does not generate any texts, just the commas.**

> Thank you for your time guys.